# Loop through files and list those not containing a string

Tags: linux

I am attempting to loop through a list of files in my directory that are of folders, if so, then list the subdirectory of these folders, and when in that subdirectory, only list those files not matching the grep expression. However, I get nothing returned with the `grep` expression included.

For example:

```
for file in "ML"*; do if [ -d "$file" ]; then ls "$file" | grep -q -F "venv" ; fi; done
```

Will print out nothing.

The subdirectory looks like the following:

```
MachineLearning     ROC.png         bin         requirements.txt    venv
ACTION_batched.py       PUT3.py             test1.py
ACTION_custom.py        RML             test2.py
Case scenarios.docx     Tutorials           venv
ENV_DIR             act_2.py            week1
Introduction to essay.docx  bin             week2
MLschema.docx           cookies.js          week3
POST.py             exercises           week4
POST_T.py           plots               week5
PUT.py              requirements.txt        week6
PUT2.py             somefig.jpeg            week7
```

Comment: If you want `grep` to print non-matching lines, use `grep -v`. Otherwise I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `grep -q` indeed doesn't print anything, the "q" is for "quiet"

Comment: @ATLief The `-v` did the trick! I was searching online and thought I read something suggesting `-q` for what I wanted to do.

Comment: @ATLief a question, is there a shorthand for selecting different names in grep? i.e. a shorthand for `grep -v "venv" | grep -v "ENV_DIR"`?

Comment: `grep -v -e 'venv' -e 'ENV_DIR'` or `grep -Ev 'venv|ENV_DIR'`

Comment: Tangentially, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Emil11 I think this question has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610642/using-grep-for-multiple-search-patterns . Note that a "pattern" can be a literal string, although you'll need to avoid or escape characters that have special meanings in a pattern context (like "-", "[", "]", "?"). For all `grep` options run `man grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the matching directories, you can simply use

```
printf '%s\n' ML*/venv/
```

Maybe pipe to `cut -d / -f1` if you want just the directory names.

That will not work entirely correctly if you have directory names with newlines; perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

The problem with your attempt is that `grep -q` does not print anything. A minimal fix would be to remove the `-q`; but of course, this is possible to solve with a single wildcard, as above.

If you want the directories which do not match (for which the minimal fix would be `grep -v` to negate the search), try something like

```
for file in ML*/*/; do
    case $file in
     */venv/) continue;;
    esac
    : continue with "$file"
done
```

The final trailing slash restricts the wildcard to only match directories; if you want to match regular files, too, you'll have to take it out from the `case` expression for matching `venv`, too.

The `continue` keyword abandons the current iteration of the innermost `for` or `while` loop, and skips to the next iteration (or the end of the loop, if this was the last iteration).

The `case` syntax can seem intimidating or cryptic if you have not come across it before, but you get used to it quickly. It is quite versatile, and lets you specify alternatives easily, like

```
    */venv/ | */ENV_DIR/) continue;;
```

It is also portable back to the original Unix v7 Bourne shell.

Bash and Ksh have an extended globbing facility which let you say things like `ML*/!(venv)` but it's not portable.

Comment: I actually was thinking to get all files besides the one provided in the `grep` expression, so anything but `venv`. The suggested wildcard is a nice hack! although I was attempting to use loops/if-else because I then wanted to implement further functions in it.

Comment: See updated answer now.

Comment: These are extremely helpful options! I currently am reading `A practice guide to linux commands`, and they explain the `case` statement very well, so your example is easy to digest. The only part I'm stuck in understanding is the following: `: continue with "$file"`, is there an article to learn about `: continue with`? Additionally, how can I implement the case condition into an `if` condition, for example, I thought: - ```if [ -d "$file" == */venv ] ```  would match, however it just throws `zsh: = not found`.

Comment: `:` is just a no-op. Your `if` attempt mixes the `-d` operator which simply accepts a single argument with the `=` operator which requires two.

Comment: The `zsh` shell is probably something you should mention in your question; the assumption on Linux would usually be that you are asking about Bash. But both shells are backwards-compatible with `sh` so my solution should work for both.